# Alternating background colours for my comments system

Tags: html, css, colors

Please i need your help with how to alternate background colours for my comments system. So that red and blue will be alternating for every other element. So far this is what i'm trying to make work, but to no success.

Thanks for your time and patience.

```
  #comment :nth-child(odd) {
     background-color: red;
   }

   #comment :nth-child(even) {
      background-color: blue;
   }


     #comment {
    color: green;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px auto
     width: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you're using a browser that supports this css3 rule. IE probably definitely won't cut it.

Comment: @Jerry I know that it's fun to hate IE, but please do not spread FUD. This works perfectly well in IE9.

Comment: you're right. i'm limited to ie8, firefox, and chrome only right now. Thanks again for the help Phrogz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo. It's called `background-color`, not `bacground-color` in the second selector.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.... But it's still not working.
Thanks

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi please update your question with the typo fixed.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome. See http://jsfiddle.net/tNzJ6/. Maybe your browser does not support the `:nth-child` selector. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @iblue's fiddle works perfectly in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox.  IE8 doesn't support the :nth-child CSS selector, but if you are using jQuery then you can use it to style for IE8 and below.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 0):

change background spelling

try something like this

```
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Test Document</title>
            <style type="text/css">

            #comment tr:nth-child(even) {background:blue}
            #comment tr:nth-child(odd) {background: red}
                 #comment {
                color: green;
                margin: 5px auto;
                padding: 5px auto
                 width: 100px;
                }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <table id="comment">

            <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>test1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>test2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>test3</td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: If you only have one comment on the page then what is the point of doing alternating colors?

Comment: @Jerry `id="comment"` is applying to the entire site (it might better be named `comments`), not a single comment.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Phrogz. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="comment">
  <div>comment 1</div>
  <div>comment 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#comment div:nth-child(odd){background-color:#ff0000;}
#comment div:nth-child(even){background-color:#0000ff;}
```

To account for browsers that don't support nth-child, you could also use .odd and .even classes, and append them using javascript and some feature detection, such as modernizr.

To explain the CSS:

```
#comment is the parent
div is the child
:nth-child specifies which of these children to apply the rule to
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I see a few things that might be wrong with this.

First, make sure you're using a browser that supports this CSS3 rule.

Second, you're using the # CSS selector instead of the . selector. Do you only have one comment on the page? If the answer is no, which I know it is, then you should be using classes. Also, don't include a space in your pseudo class selectors.

You code should probably look like this

```
.comment tr:nth-child(even)
{
      background-color: blue;
}

.comment tr:nth-child(odd)
{
      background-color: red;
}

.comment tr
{
    color: green;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 5px auto
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: While the choice of `comment` as the identifier in the CSS isn't quite appropriate, it appears to actually be the wrapper around the comments, not the comments themselves (since the OP is trying to style the children of the `#comment`).